# Addon or Script to Cycle Snap Type via Keymap?

Tags: python, scripting, snapping, keymap

I have been doing a lot of work recently in blender where i am constantly cycling between Face, Edge and Vertex Snapping, i wondered if there was a way to Cycle through the 3 options with a keymap (Spare mouse button in my case). I managed to cobble something together that works, but it only works in Edit mode, i'd like this to also work in Object Mode, is there a different set of objects that need referencing? Here is what i have so far:

````
import bpy



class SnapCycle(bpy.types.Operator):

bl_idname = 'object.snap_cycle'

bl_label = 'Cycles through snap modes.'



def execute(self, context):

ts = context.tool_settings

if 'VERTEX' in ts.snap_elements: # Vertex snap mode

ts.snap_elements = {'EDGE'} # Switch to edge snap mode

elif 'EDGE' in ts.snap_elements: # Edge snap mode

ts.snap_elements = {'FACE'} # Switch to face snap mode

else: # Face snap mode

ts.snap_elements = {'VERTEX'} # Switch to vertex snap mode

return {'FINISHED'}



def register():

bpy.utils.register_class(SnapCycle)



def unregister():

bpy.utils.unregister_class(SnapCycle)



if __name__ == "__main__":

register()
```
````